# AWS S3 deploy sync with GIT

Tags: git, amazon-s3, deployment, single-page-application

I have an private git repo hosted on GitLab.

My stack is:

- one rails json REST api hosted on Heroku
- one single-page-application that comunicates with the json api hosted on AWS S3

Push code to production in back-end is simple via `git push heroku master`.
But I have no automation system to front-end. I have to pull, build and upload the static files to s3 bucket.

all I need is some automation system to push my front-end application to production as simple as `git push s3 master`.

I know there is some continuous integration like jenkins, but maintain an dedicated server just to manage my deploy system sounds too overkill to me. My intuition is there is some service that I couldn't find just *googling it*.

Comment: you could use gitlab-ci for this purpose, or semaphore ci for example

Answer (score 0):

try to use the aws cli tool and then sync the entire git folder:

```
aws s3 sync git_folder s3://bucket_name/folder/
```

Comment: this does not seens to solve my problem. Because I'm working with more people and don't wanna have the risk of deploy over the non sync'ed changes.

eg:

1 : someone deploy some stuff
2 : I make changes and forget of pull, or he forget to push
3 : I deploy with this aws command
4 : now I lost his changes

Comment: well, that's exactly why you would use a tool like Jenkins to do that. If insist on deploying from developer machine, then build a small script to handle it:

Comment: 1) checkout develop branch to some new folder
2) do the sync to S3
I assume you work in feature branches and only deploy from a single branch.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this if you write your own server side hooks. Hooks in git are scripts that are triggered/run when certain events happen.

So if I understand your question correctly, what you want could be done after push to s3's master branch as a post-receive hook to build and upload the front-end to s3. Also a pre-receive hook works in the same manner, it provides the option to reject the push based on something you define.

You can find the documentation here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks